Linear fit for lower bound of scatter plot in python
I have a set of datapoints in 3 columns that I need to analyze multiple times, so doing it by hand is quite time consuming.
For example, this is my data:
d = {'Point': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40], 
 'Interval 1': [92.417, 117.364, 126.302, 121.816, 126.083, 85.267, 84.977, 85.610, 84.909, 84.535, 85.024, 85.059, 84.798, 84.001, 84.157, 104.918,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
'Interval 2':['','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',157.884,163.604,122.905,84.770,83.386,83.530,83.418,83.423,83.350,83.618,83.486,83.846,83.622,83.796,83.942,84.068,84.379,84.175,84.010,84.439,84.479,84.599,84.998,101.860]}

Here, converted to dataframe:
data = pd.DataFrame(d)

The data is then filtered so that I only have the lowest 10% of values in Interval 1 and 2.
I look for the min value in both columns:
min_val = min(data['Interval 1'].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').min(), data['Interval 2'].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').min())

Then I need to convert the emty strings to NaN
cols = ['Interval 1', 'Interval 2']

data[cols] = data[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

And replace NaN values with 0, to be able to filter:
data = data.fillna(0)

df_filter = data[(data['Interval 1']<=min_val*1.10) & (data['Interval 2']<=min_val*1.10)]

Now, I can create linear regressions for the 2 columns but I need it actually on the lower boundary of the data.
I add an excel plot for visualization purposes:

With python, like with Excel, I get the linear fits based on all the data points of the series, described by the upper constants.
What I need is a way to get the linear fits for the lower bounds - in this case, for the green and light blue points filtered by hand, as those have different slope then the whole dataset.
Is there a way to do it? I have searched quite a while and did not find anything like this requierement.
Maybe someone has an advise how the lower bound data could be filtered to just create the regression line for the filteres data?
Thank you in advance for your support.
